# static const arrays

Tags: c++

If I read this in a class as a data member, is the `static` referring to the entire expression (the array itself) or the elements of the array?

`static const int* array[100];`

Is the array, `array`, static, or does the array contain 100 `static const int pointers` ?

I'm assuming the former, but the way the word `const` changes meaning makes me wonder if `static` also changes meaning based on where in the expression it exists. In the above, the pointer `array` is not `const` yet the elements of the array *are* `const`, so I wonder if the pointer of the array is `static`.

Comment: you sure about that? `const int* const array[100]` would ensure a constant array

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html

Comment: @KhalidTaha see other answers; your comment is not accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static`, `extern` and `register` apply to the variable you declare, to `array` in this example.

So, you get a static array of 100 pointers to constant integers.

Comment: By constant integers, you mean they can't be modified via the array's pointer, right?

Comment: note quite.  probably more correct as "they can't be modified via the pointer in the array".  they can't be modified via the array's pointer anyway because the array's pointer has no bearing on the pointers in the array.

Comment: @thang Nice, I knew the difference, but wrote it incorrectly, what I wanted to write was "pointers in the array" and English isn't my native language :)

Answer (score 4):

**C++11 7.1.1 Storage class specifiers:**
§5

> The static specifier can be applied only to names of variables and functions and to anonymous unions (9.5).
>   There can be no static function declarations within a block, nor any static function parameters. **A static
>   specifier used in the declaration of a variable declares the variable to have static storage duration** (3.7.1),
>   unless accompanied by the thread_local specifier, which declares the variable to have thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2). A static specifier can be used in declarations of class members; 9.4 describes its effect.
>   For the linkage of a name declared with a static specifier, see 3.5.

So what are you declaring in the code example?

```
static const int* array[100];
```

Obviously, you are declaring the variable `array` So the `static` applies to `array`.
Do not confuse *storage class specifier* with *cv-qualifiers* the former applies to the variable being declared while the latter applies to the *type*.

Comment: +1 Good to know about the difference between cv-quals and storage specifiers.

Comment: I'm normally against quoting standards. But when the question is about such a careful and (to some minds) subtle distinction, quoting the standard is the right thing to do.